# Add a quantity field to Ajax add to cart button on WooCommerce shop page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to Woocommerce. I was trying to show the quantity box in the shop page. I have used the below code and it's working as expected:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'handsome_bearded_guy_select_variations' );

function handsome_bearded_guy_select_variations() {
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
}
```

But the problem is that ajax add to cart button got replaced with default one.

How can I enable back the ajax functionality on add to cart button **with quantity field** for Woocommerce archives pages?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Updated** *on 2021*

*For WooCommerce versions from 3.2 to 5+, Optimized jQuery code and Removed a quantity bug. Added quantity reset after add to cart.*

---

The following custom function is hooked in `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` filter hook and adds a quantity input field to each product on WooCommerce archives pages and other product loops. We use here mostly the original WooCommerce code.

A bit of jQuery code is necessary to update the `data-quantity` attribute on the add to cart button when customer changes the quantity. Some styling might be needed, depending on your client wishes *(and on your theme)*.

An additional section to **hide the "View cart" button** is located at the end.

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        // Get the necessary classes
        $class = implode( ' ', array_filter( array(
            'button',
            'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
            $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
            $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
        ) ) );

        // Embedding the quantity field to Ajax add to cart button
        $html = sprintf( '%s<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
            woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false ),
            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
        );
    }
    return $html;
}

add_action( 'wp_footer' , 'archives_quantity_fields_script' );
function archives_quantity_fields_script(){
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function($){
            // Update data-quantity
            $(document.body).on('click input', 'input.qty', function() {
                $(this).parent().parent().find('a.ajax_add_to_cart').attr('data-quantity', $(this).val());
                $(".added_to_cart").remove(); // Optional: Removing other previous "view cart" buttons
            }).on('click', '.add_to_cart_button', function(){
                var button = $(this);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    button.parent().find('.quantity > input.qty').val(1); // reset quantity to 1
                }, 1000); // After 1 second

            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active theme). 

Tested and works on WooCommerce version 4.1.1 and WordPress 4.5.1 on Storefront theme.*

---

**Hiding "View cart" button** *(when using Ajax add to cart)*:

1). You can add this CSS rule to the styles.css file located in your active theme:

```css
a.added_to_cart.wc-forward {
    display:none;
}
```

2). You can use the following hoocked function *(first option is the best way)*:

```
add_action( 'wp_head' , 'hide_ajax_view_cart_button' );
function hide_ajax_view_cart_button(){
    if( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ): ?>
    <style>
        a.added_to_cart.wc-forward {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
    <?php endif;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme).*

Comment: Maybe is there, but I can not find, so can you advise the code to add and remove products by clicking on quantity +/-  or maybe I can try to modify the current code for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Does everything as above, without the "quantity bug".

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        // Get the necessary classes
        $class = implode( ' ', array_filter( array(
            'button',
            'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
            $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
            $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
        ) ) );

        // Adding embeding <form> tag and the quantity field
        $html = sprintf( '%s%s<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>%s',
        '<form class="cart">',
        woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false ),
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ),
        '</form>'
        );
    }
    return $html;
}

add_action( 'wp_footer' , 'archives_quantity_fields_script' );
function archives_quantity_fields_script(){
    //if( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ): ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function($){
            // Update quantity on 'a.button' in 'data-quantity' attribute (for ajax)
            $(".add_to_cart_button.product_type_simple").on('click', function() { var $button = $(this); $button.data('quantity', $button.parent().find('input.qty').val()); });        
            // remove old "view cart" text, only need latest one thanks!
            $(document.body).on("adding_to_cart", function() {
                $("a.added_to_cart").remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php //endif;
}
```

References:

@LoicTheAztec's entry above 11 Feb 2018.

@braciawrite's and @andrewmclagan's GitHub entries on 11 Dec 2015 and 15 Mar 2018 respectively.

https://gist.github.com/webaware/6260326

Note:

Code should perform the check when "add_to_cart" button is pressed, not on quantity change.

I've commented out the if and endif statements under function "archives_quantity_fields_script" as I am running this code on a custom page with WooCommerce products.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this code works as of 27th Jul 2019. Accepted answer has syntax error

Comment: As of WooCommerce 4.0 this solution seems to no longer work.

Comment: Anyone here to help me am in October 2020 and still quantity is not updating

Comment: WordPress 5.5.1

Answer (score 1):

It took me a whole day to get this working - but here is the code that worked for me. Add to your functions.php - its adapted from the above and I'm on WooCommerce 5.0.0

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        // Get the necessary classes
        $class = implode( ' ', array_filter( array(
            'button',
            'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
            $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
            $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
        ) ) );

        // Adding embeding <form> tag and the quantity field
        $html = sprintf( '%s%s<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>%s',
        '<form class="cart">',
        woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false ),
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ),
        '</form>'
        );
    }
    return $html;
}

add_action( 'wp_footer' , 'archives_quantity_fields_script' );

function archives_quantity_fields_script(){
    //if( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ): ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
        $( document ).on( 'change', '.quantity .qty', function() {
            $( this ).parent( '.quantity' ).next( '.add_to_cart_button' ).attr( 'data-quantity', $( this ).val() );
            //alert("Changed");
        });
    });
        
        jQuery(function($) {
            // Update quantity on 'a.button' in 'data-quantity' attribute (for ajax) 
            $(".add_to_cart_button.product_type_simple").on('click', function() {
                var $button = $(this);
                $button.data('quantity', $button.parent().find('input.qty').val());
            });
            // remove old "view cart" text, only need latest one thanks!
            $(document.body).on("adding_to_cart", function() {
                $("a.added_to_cart").remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php //endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method which seems to work well in Woo 3+

```
<?php
/**
 * Add quantity field on the archive page.
 */
function custom_quantity_field_archive() {

    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );

    if ( ! $product->is_sold_individually() && 'variable' != $product->get_type() && $product->is_purchasable() ) {
    woocommerce_quantity_input( array( 'min_value' => 1, 'max_value' => $product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $product->get_stock_quantity() ) );
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_quantity_field_archive', 0, 9 );

/**
 * Enqueue the JavaScript.
 */
function custom_add_to_cart_quantity_handler() {

wc_enqueue_js( '
    jQuery( ".post-type-archive-product" ).on( "click", ".quantity input", function() {
        return false;
    });
    jQuery( ".post-type-archive-product" ).on( "change input", ".quantity .qty", function() {
        var add_to_cart_button = jQuery( this ).parents( ".product" ).find( ".add_to_cart_button" );
        
        // For AJAX add-to-cart actions
        add_to_cart_button.attr( "data-quantity", jQuery( this ).val() );

        // For non-AJAX add-to-cart actions
        add_to_cart_button.attr( "href", "?add-to-cart=" +   add_to_cart_button.attr( "data-product_id" ) + "&quantity=" + jQuery( this ).val() );
    });
' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_add_to_cart_quantity_handler' );
```

There may be several options for the jQuery, depending on what Ajax actions are on your page.