# WP minimum Quantity at single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the following answer code that enable product quantity fields in shop and archive pages: 
[Show quantity box with add to cart ajax enabled in Woocommerce shop page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48722178/show-quantity-box-with-add-to-cart-ajax-enabled-in-woocommerce-shop-page/48728429#48728429) and its work great.

This code work fine the problem is: when i am on a single product page and product has a minimum amount to order (5 for example) the code put the same minimum amount at the releated products (even if they dont have a minimum amount for order)

[image: Picture from single product page]

Comment: If you use an existing answer code without making changes to it, just add the link instead. Now the second part of your question is unclear and not understandable. Please try to reword it. Thanks.

Comment: I'll try again. First of all thanks I'll do it next time. This code work fine the problem is: when i am on a single product page and product has a minimum amount to order (5 for example) the code put the same minimum amount at the releated products (even if they dont have a minimum amount for order)

Comment: Please, is better to edit your question instead, as it will be read by every one.