# Custom quantity field functionality issue on WooCommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am using *"[Show quantity box with add to cart ajax enabled in Woocommerce shop page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48722178/show-quantity-box-with-add-to-cart-ajax-enabled-in-woocommerce-shop-page/48728429#48728429)"* answer code successfully, to display a quantity box to the Ajax add to cart buttons of my products on the category pages. That allows customer to add to cart multiple quantities at once for simple products on archive pages.

**My question:** How do I can change hooks involved on my archive pages to change the location of a custom quantity field for my simple products?

If you take a look at a **simple** product *(not variable products)* 
in [my website shop page](http://browns.kurvecreative.co.uk/shop/), the top quantity selector is the Ajax add to cart function, I want it to be positioned where the other quantity selector is (or replace it if possible), not be positioned above the products title.

Reason I have added this function to override the Ajax that the website currently has is because the old one only allowed me to add 1 quantity on anything when using Ajax.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should not attempt to re-order hooks as even if successful it would potentially break other functionality if not now then in future if other plugins are added.

Your options are to:
Use the filter to remove a piece of functionality from one hook and add it to the other in the order you want.
Or 
Create an override template in your theme that either has the hooks called in the order you want (as mentioned not recommended) or add your own hook/functionality in the place you want it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I see someone say about removing the hooks and then re adding them as a different priority. I only ideally need to remove the product title hook and re order it above the new quantity selector, then I'll just use CSS to hide the display of the other quantity. Wondering if you may know a way to find all the relevant hooks to the page that I view? I'm not that great with coding as I mentioned I have only been creating wordpress websites for a year so still fumbling at times

Comment: You can try look through the woo documentation but it is not beginner friendly and sometimes has mistakes so if you are able to find the hook and need more help on how to make use of it that would narrow things down: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html